# Updating value of input html using javascript fails

Tags: javascript, html

I have a simple html:

```
<td><input type="text" style="border:none;" size="12" id="titleId" name="title" value="333"></td>
```

and I use the code below to update the value of the input:

```
document.getElementById('titleId').value = "999";
```

However, when I click "inspect element" the value is still "333", but on the page it shows "999".
I need to update the value to "999" for pdf printing purposes.

How can I update the values using js?

Comment: No, the `value` _attribute_ might still be `333` but the `value` property will be changed which is what is reflected in the text value of the `<input>` (ie, what you see). Changes to element properties aren't always reflected in their attributes. Think of attributes as a value initialiser only

Comment: How can I do what I need? (change value attribute)

Comment: You shouldn't need to

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In addition to @Phil's Comment, this is how you can change attribute's value via `javascript`

```js
function test(){
  document.getElementById("in").setAttribute("value", "999");
}
```

```html
<input id="in" value="333"/>
<button onclick="test()">Click Me</button>
```

Comment: or the shorter one: document.getElementById("titleId").setAttribute("value", "999"); 
 Thanks both Ali and @Phil

Comment: "You can accept an answer in 4 minutes"))